# Term for "Directed acyclic graph with exactly one sink and one source"

Tags: terminology, graph-theory, reference-request

There's a theorem/lemma that states that a finite directed acyclic graph (DAG) has at least one sink and at least one source. Is there a term for a (finite) DAG with ***exactly*** one sink and one source?

(And while you're at it, any good background references for someone whose research just took a left turn into such DAGs?)

Comment: I guess you're talking only about finite directed acyclic graphs?

Comment: @Joel: Yes I was only thinking about finite DAGs.

Comment: Aeryk, you can edit to change your first sentence to add the finiteness hypothesis, since it isn't true for all directed acyclic graphs. For example, the integers under the successor relation is a DAG with no sources or sinks.

Comment: And I guess (please excuse this trivial remark) one needs to say "nonempty" as well, since the empty graph is directed and acyclic, but has no sources or sinks.

Comment: Or, "non-empty well-orderable graphs with no infinite directed paths". $\;$ 

Comment: @JDH: A better statement than adding "nonempty" near the beginning would be to add "in each component" at the end.  This gives generically a stronger statement than the one OP started with, and covers the $\emptyset$ case as well.

Answer (score 5):

In
Fully Dynamic Transitive Closure in Plane Dags with One Source and One Sink (1994)
by Thore Husfeldt
this is called a `source-sink graph` (or short `st-graph`) by Definition (1).

Comment: Urgh. That's an ugly name :-/

Comment: The term *st-graph* is well-established in the literature for over twenty years (e.g., Tamassia's "Drawing algorithms for planar st-graphs," 1990). Maybe because I'm accustomed to it, I find "st-graph" natural.

Comment: "st-DAG" = "source-target DAG"

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the term "interval" used for this notion, at least in the context of subgraphs of a larger DAG.  I'm not saying it's a good term, just that I've seen it used.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the previously mentioned st-dag or st-DAG (source-target DAG) the term "two-terminal directed acyclic graph" is also often used.